# Is my conversion from assembly to c code correct?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I have a problem that asks to convert assembly code to C code.

I've made an attempt to convert the code and I think I got it mostly right but I am confused by the `leaq` instruction.

```
looper:
   movl  $o, %eax
   movl  $o, %edx
   jmp   .L2

.L4:
   movq  (%rsi, %rdx, 8), %rcx
   cmpq  %rcx, %rax
   jl    .L3
   movq  %rax, %rcx

.L3:
   leaq  1(%rcx), %rax
   addq  $1, %rdx

.L2:
   cmpq  %rdi, %rdx
   jl    .L4
   rep ret
```

Here is the C code that I got:

```
long looper(long n, long *a) {
  long i;
  long x = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (x < a[i]) {
      x = a[i] + 1;
    }
    x = a[i];
  }

  return x;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a unit test that can verify it works correctly?

Comment: I don't I guess I could run my c code and see what the output is but I don't know how to run the assembly with the same arguments to see if the output of both matches.

Comment: What's the point of `x = a[i] + 1;` since you immediately overwrite it with `x = a[i]`?

Comment: The whole loop is equivalent to just `x = a[n-1];`

Comment: You can always stuff this inside a C wrapper to test it. Just saying.

Comment: My comment assumes that your C translation is correct, which is actually your question. I don't know assembly well enough to know if it actually is.

Comment: I suspect there should be `else`

Comment: haha yeah I missed the else there after the if statement

Comment: What is `$o`? Global variable?

Comment: @JL2210 : pretty sure that was a transcription error and was meant to be `$0`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, there seems to be an error in your assembly: looks like `$o` should be `$0` (zero).

Your C code is almost correct, there are some errors:

1. The order of the branches generated by the `jl .L3` instruction is quite significant, in fact, if `%rax < %rcx` the branch is taken, and the instruction `movq  %rax, %rcx` is ignored. On the other hand, if the branch is NOT taken, then that move is executed *before* stepping into `.L3`. So you basically swapped the two branches in your C code.
2. The value of `a[i]` is not used directly every time, but it is saved in the `%rcx` register before being used. Both `movq  %rax, %rcx` and `movq (%rsi, %rdx, 8), %rcx` assign to `%rcx`, then the value is passed from `%rcx` to `%rax`, so `%rcx` should be treated as a different variable. This means that writing `x = a[i] + 1;` is wrong. It should be:

   ```
   tmp = a[i];
   /* ... */
   x = tmp + 1;
   ```

The resulting C code should be something like this:

```
int64_t looper(int64_t n, int64_t *arr) {
    int64_t result; // rax
    int64_t tmp;    // rcx
    int64_t i;      // rdx

    result = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp = arr[i];

        if (result >= tmp)
            tmp = result;

        result = tmp + 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

As an addition, compiling your binary using `as -o prog prog.s` and then disassembling with Radare2 gives this rather simple control flow graph:

```
    looper ();
        0x08000040      mov eax, 0
        0x08000045      mov edx, 0
    ,=< 0x0800004a      jmp 0x8000060
    |
    |   ; JMP XREF from 0x08000063 (looper)
  .---> 0x0800004c      mov rcx, qword [rsi + rdx*8]
  | |   0x08000050      cmp rax, rcx
,=====< 0x08000053      jl 0x8000058
| | |   0x08000055      mov rcx, rax
| | |
| | |   ; JMP XREF from 0x08000053 (looper)
`-----> 0x08000058      lea rax, qword [rcx + 1]
  | |   0x0800005c      add rdx, 1
  | |
  | |   ; JMP XREF from 0x0800004a (looper)
  | `-> 0x08000060      cmp rdx, rdi
  `===< 0x08000063      jl 0x800004c
        0x08000065      ret
```

Comment: Think you mean `tmp` and not `reg_rcx`

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you, classic copy pasting error :')

Comment: Assuming that this is on some non-absurd platforms, the use of `long` is correct. Otherwise, `long long` can be used.

Comment: @JL2210 I decided not to use `long` since it is platform dependent, and you cannot infer data types from raw assembly that easily. `int64_t` is correct, `long` *may be correct*.

Comment: @JL2210 and Marco: the function args arrived in RDI and RSI, so this is the x86-64 System V ABI.  `long` is a 64-bit type there, unlike in Windows x64.  (LP64 vs. LLP64).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models.  But yes, `int64_t` is much better and has no dependency on little details like this.  A DeathStation 9000 C implementation on x86-64 might have `long long` being a 128-bit type.  But if the optional type `int64_t` exists at all, it's required to be exactly 64 bits, no padding, and 2's complement.  (Signed overflow is still UB though.)